# How to create a php url redirection for nicer links

Tags: redirect, ads

I'm looking for a way to make a URL redirection for affiliate links on my website.

Something like : **site.com/go/keyword**

I know there is many plugins for doiing this, but i don't like plugin, and i love to learn new things.

I imagine 2 custom fields for each posts with :

- keyword
- url to redirect to

But i have no idea how to process this redirect file.

Any help or advice is welcome.

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the answear of @alexander & of @dboris

here is the final solution :

1. Create a page to handle redirections
2. add to `functions.php`

```
    add_action('init', function() {
        $page_id = 2100;
        $page_data = get_post($page_id);

        if(!is_object($page_data)) {
            return;
        }

        add_rewrite_tag('%affiliate%','([^/]+)');
        add_rewrite_rule(
            'go/([^/]+)/?$',
            'index.php?pagename=' . $page_data->post_name . '&affiliate=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );
    });
```

Replace `%affiliate%` and `affiliate` by the tag you wish to use.
Replace `page_id` with the ID of your page defined on step 1.

Add a page model that you assign to page defined on sted 1 and add this code to it :

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'meta_key'         => 'booking_slug',
    'meta_value'       => $aff,
    'post_type'        => 'hotel'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $cc_args );
if($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo get_field('booking_affiliate');
endwhile;
endif;
```

Need to secure a bit this stuff, and make the redirection using the way you want!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [add_rewrite_rule](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) to register a new URL, and then also create a new page & template to handle where to link off to.

For example:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    $page_id = 2;
    $page_data = get_post($page_id);

    if(!is_object($page_data)) {
        return;
    }

    add_rewrite_rule(
        $page_data->post_name . '/go/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=' . $page_data->post_name . '&affiliate=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
});
```

Replace the `$page_id` with the correct ID of a new page which will handle the links.

You also need to use add_filter to setup the variable:

```
add_filter('query_vars', function($vars) {
    $vars[] = "affiliate";
    return $vars;
});
```

Your new page & template will then access this value using [get_query_var](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) and redirect accordingly:

```
$affiliate = get_query_var('affiliate', false);
// Do whatever lookup you need here to get the actual link to redirect to
wp_redirect($url);
exit;
```

UPDATE:
You will also need to visit the permalinks admin page so that the new rewrite rules are applied. You can also test the rules are working using the [Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/), (although it's a little old now).

Comment: ok, by reading your post again & again, i think i start to understand it. 
what you want me to do, is to add a page in my wp pages. Add your rewrite rule to my functions.php and then add a page template in my theme and assign it to the page created before ? In this page, i will be able to get all the data i needed ! That seems to be logic

Comment: so : i created a page : "book" with id 2100
i set $page_id to 2100
i created a page model "book".
i assign this model to the page "book".
in page model, i added code for add filter.
i save back my permalinks to generate them
but if i go on mysite.com/go/test 
i go on a 404 page.

Comment: You need to also visit the permalinks page so that the new rewrite rules are refreshed. Sorry, I should have mentioned that (updated my answer)

Comment: Hi Alexander, as sait just before, "i save back my permalinks to generate them", but it doesn't change anything. I'll look at the solution of dboris. But maybe i have an idea. I add .html to all my pages, cpt, & articles slug. So maybe i have a conflict with this ?

Comment: You can test that with the [Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/). Just try both links `mysite.com/go/test` and `mysite.com/go/test.html` to see what happens. dboris's solution will work just fine, perhaps slightly more elegant than mine, however it may have the same problem if you are altering your URLs - give it a try and let us know.

Comment: Hello, rewrite rules inspector says : book/go/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pagename=book&affiliate=$matches[1]  --- so i don't know why, but it add /book/ ( page name )

Comment: so, if i go on site.com/book/go/test  i have my page working, with my echo 'test';
now need to get rid of /book/ ( or at least, it doesn't matter if it stay like this ^^ ). I continue with trying to get my data ^^

Comment: ok, for making site.com/go/test i replace : "$page_data->post_name . '/go/([^/]+)/?$'," with "'go/([^/]+)/?$',". and it works.

Comment: now i need to undestand rest of your code :D 
i think i should better use same slug for cloack url than for hotel slug. Like this i can get $_GET['affiliate'] and make a wp_query for get custom field for post with slug $_GET['affiliate'] is this good ?

Comment: starts well... "$_GET['affiliate'] doesn't return value

Comment: if i use your code, and i echo $affiliate; it returns blank

Answer (score 1):

This solution works without creating new pages or changing anything.

We will:
1. Set up a new rewrite rule and add a new query variable
2. Catch that case in a 'pre_get_posts' hook, fetch the post we need and do the redirection

Note that if you have multiple posts with the same `keyword_meta` value, this might not work as planned. I have not implemented the checks for this, the first matching post will be selected.

Code should go into the `functions.php` or similar:

```
add_action( 'init',
    function () {
        add_rewrite_rule(
            '^(go)\/([^\/]+)$',
            'index.php?redirection=$matches[2]',
            'top'
        );

        add_filter( 'query_vars',
            function ( $vars ) {
                $vars[] = "redirection";

                return $vars;
            } 
        );
    }
);

add_action( 'pre_get_posts',
    function ( $query ) {
        if ( $redirection = get_query_var( 'redirection' ) ) {

            // Change this:
            $keyword_meta         = 'keyword_meta_field_name';
            $redirection_url_meta = 'redirection_url_meta_field_name';
            $post_type            = 'post';

            $args = [
                'meta_key'       => $keyword_meta,
                'meta_value'     => $redirection,
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'post_type'      => $post_type,
            ];

            $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            $posts      = $post_query->get_posts();

            // If no posts found, redirect back to referer
            if ( count( $posts ) < 1 ) {
                wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
            }

            $redirection_url = get_post_meta( $posts[0]->ID, $redirection_url_meta, true );

            // If no redirection URL found, redirect back to referer
            if ( ! $redirection_url ) {
                wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
            }

            // Finally, do the redirection
            if ( headers_sent() ) {
                echo( "<script>location.href='$redirection_url'</script>" );
            } else {
                header( "Location: $redirection_url" );
            }
            exit;
        }

        return $query;
    }
);
```

**Please do not forget to refresh your Permalinks in the dashboard (open Settings > Permalinks and click on Save Changes).**